# configsvr and nojournal

Tags: mongodb-3.2

trying to start mongo config server :

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/config-1 --port 27019 --logpath /data/config-1.log --fork --journal
```

gives:

```
F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: BadValue: nojournal is not allowed when configsvr is specified
```

Can anyone advise on how to resolve this one?

Comment: The version of mongo installed is 3.2.10

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24551) of mongo 3.2